# RabbitMQ grouping messages as one message ie coalescing messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-integration

I'm trying to understand the best way to coalesce or chunk incoming messages in RabbitMQ (using Spring AMQP or the Java client directly).

In other words I would like to take say 100 incoming messages and combine them as 1 and resend it to another queue in a reliable (correctly `ACK`ed way). I believe this is called  the [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) pattern in EIP.

I know Spring Integration [provides an aggregator solution](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.M3/spring-integration-reference/html/aggregator.html) but the implementation looks like its not fail safe (that is it looks like it has to ack and consume messages to build the coalesced message thus if you shutdown it down while its doing this you will loose messages?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `<amqp-inbound-channel-adapter/>` `tx-size` attribute to 100, the container will ack every 100 messages so this should prevent message loss.

However, you might want to make the send of the aggregated message (on the 100th receive) transactional so you can confirm the broker has the message before the ack for the inbound messages.

Comment: I think the prefetchCount (`org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#setPrefetchCount`) (which is correlated with the tx size) is what I need to play with.

Comment: No; see `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute()` and `BlockingQueueConsumer.commitIfNecessary`; if the container is not transactional, just the 'last' delivery tag is acked (within a loop of txSize messages). The prefetch is adjusted, if it is smaller than the txSize... `int actualPrefetchCount = prefetchCount > txSize ? prefetchCount : txSize;`.

Comment: Yes I think I understand and I think I need to write my own SimpleMessageListenerContainer to handoff the prefetched messages taking transactions into account. Right now the message container is designed on single messages (ie there is no `onMessage(Collection<Message>...)` ). Basically it looks like I need to write my own `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer`

Comment: One thing I failed to mention, txSize is the number of receive ATTEMPTS - so, if the receiveTimeout is low, every time we loop around without finding a message contributes to the loop count. So, in this case, you COULD ack at < 100 - this means this won't work, unless you set the receiveTimeout to really high value (which may not be a good idea). So, maybe instead of using the inbound adapter, you could use the SMLC with acknowledge=MANUAL and use a ChannelAwareListener to do your own ack (after you have secured the aggregated result in the other queue.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment directly on the Spring Integration library, so I'll speak generally in terms of RabbitMQ.

If you're not 100% convinced by the Spring Integration implementation of the Aggregator and are going to try to implement it yourself then I would recommend avoiding using `tx` which uses transactions under the hood in RabbitMQ.

Transactions in RabbitMQ are slow and you will definitely suffer performance problems if you're building a high traffic/throughput system.

Rather I would suggest you take a look at *Publisher Confirms* which is an extension to AMQP implemented in RabbitMQ. Here is an introduction to it when it was new http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/.

You will need to tweak the prefetch setting to get the performance right, take a look at http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/11/some-queuing-theory-throughput-latency-and-bandwidth/ for some details.

All the above gives you some background to help solve your problem. The implementation is rather straightforward.

When creating your consumer you will need to ensure you set it so that ACK is required.

1. Dequeue n messages, as you dequeue you will need to make note of the DeliveryTag for each message (this is used to ACK the message)
2. Aggregate the messages into a new message
3. Publish the new message
4. ACK each dequeued message

One thing to note is that if your consumer dies after 3 and before 4 has completed then those messages that weren't ACK'd will be reprocessed when it comes back to life

Comment: +1 Spring AMQP already does pending confirms. The reason I need TX is that I need to be able support commit/rollback for transaction resource synchronization (ie submit the message after the db transaction has committed or rollback). I'm going/want to create my own in memory transactions (ie push a list of messages on db commit) so that I can get the performance your talking about... but thats a different issue I have to resolve :)